# Why does git store my SSH identity in gnome, but not KDE?

Tags: kde, git, ssh-agent

I'm used to git only prompting me for my SSH passphrase the first time I need to authenticate to a server.

On the system I'm currently on, this only works in a Gnome session. If I start a KDE session, git will require the SSH passphrase every time it authenticates.

Explicitly using the `ssh-add` comand works around this - after I enter the passphrase, I won't be asked for it again.

Why is git able to implicitly use the ssh agent in one desktop, but not the other? Is there some environment variable or .bashrc thing I need to change?

Comment: I don't know about KDE, but in Gnome, gnome-keyring-daemon is the process that keeps your ssh keys unlocked.

Comment: Apparently KDE's equivalent is KWallet: https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/08/12/git-how-to-avoid-typing-your-password-repeatedly/

Answer (score 1):

SSH agent is not started by KDE by default. You need to install package like [AUR (en) - plasma-workspace-agent-ssh](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/plasma-workspace-agent-ssh/) to start that. And install `ksshaskpass` to make it ask paraphrase. Then create an autostart file (KDE4: `~/.kde4/Autostart/ssh-add.sh`, KDE Plasma: `~/.config/autostart/ssh-add.sh`) with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh-add </dev/null
```

reference: [KDE Wallet - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE_Wallet)